Load RDA object from a private GitHub
I have a RDA object stored on a private github repo of mine. I'd like to load that object into R, but I can't figure out how to so do. Does anyone know how to do this?

First, you need to create a github token
Run and follow instructions on the navigator, then copy the "token"
usethis::create_github_token()   # then copy the token
gh_token <- "<write_your_token_here>"

Next: you need to set a environment path package gh uses to get the token. Check the name of the environment path with check_envar_name. In my case it is GITHUB_PAT_GITHUB_COM
gitcreds::gitcreds_cache_envvar("https://github.com/<your_user>/<your_repo>")

So:
Sys.setenv(GITHUB_PAT_GITHUB_COM = gh_token)

Finally download the file:
gh::gh("/repos/{repo_spec}/contents/{path}", 
       repo_spec = "<your_user>/<your_repo>",
       path = "path_in_repo/some.RDA",   ref = "main",  # <- main or your branch
       .destfile = "/path/to/some.RDA", 
       .accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw")

load("/path/to/some.RDA")


path_in_repo is the path of the file in the repo
EDIT
To read directly from a connection
raw_content <- gh::gh("/repos/{repo_spec}/contents/{path}", 
       repo_spec = "<your_user>/<your_repo>",
       path = "path_in_repo/some.RDA",   ref = "main", 
       .accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw")

con <- rawConnection(raw_content)
load(con)
close(con)



I personally prefer saveRDS() and readRDS() interface

This works for saving reading a file from github and saving it to a directory. But there anyway to load it directory into R without saving it to file?

I modified the code with an option to load from a variable connection. So no file is created.
But it is the same to create a temporary file (i.e.  tmp <- tempfile()) then load it, then delete it (unlink(tmp))

So I'm able to use gh() to get a "large gh_response" object. rawConnection() converts that object into a "'rawConnection' int 9" object. But when I use load(), I get an error message: the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection

Never mind! I was able to convert the gh_response using unserializeFromRaw()
